# Content length already present error soapUI 4.5.1

Tags: http-headers, soapui

I've recently started using soapUI 4.5.1 and I'm still not familiar with all the settings. I've set up a few web requests and all but one are working correctly. I'm trying to send content of type application/xml but I'm getting:

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException caused by org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present.

The same request always worked fine for me in 4.5.0. Content of request is something like this:

```
POST http://exampleHost.com/exampleRequest HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: text/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 456
Host: exampleHost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Followed by the xml.

I take it that content length is sent twice, but I don't know where, because I haven't set it anywhere. SoapUI is showing `Additional HTTP Headers for this message` as `0`.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Problem was with my settings, like I thought! Checking the "Authenciate Preemptively" check box in global HTTP settings solved the issue :)

Comment: Now it has stopped working again even though I didn't change anything - worked once then wouldn't work again, what on earth is going on?

Comment: ( I am able to resolve this by changing the 'Authorisation Type' to 'Preemptive' in 'Aut' tab of my soap request.)[http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=14356]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got in touch with SmartBear support, the problem seems to have been fixed in the latest nightly build available @ http://soapui.org/Downloads/soapui-pro-nightly-builds.html.

Answer (score 17):

I got the error to go away (in SoapUI 4.5.1) by checking the Authenticate Preemptively flag in

Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Authenticate Preemptively

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem using an authenticating development server that was requesting user credentials but actually accepted a blank or any other password. So I was leaving the password blank which worked fine in soapUI 4.5.0, but failed the way you described in 4.5.1. But I found that simply putting some text into the password appears to fix the problem.

Don't know if this relates to your case, but just in case it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is text in password and still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Soap UI pro version 4.5.1.

Finally figured out that the issue was with proxy settings.

**Resolution:**

1. Adding the target server in Exclude List for Proxy Settings has
   resolved the issue. This is the case even if the end point url is a
   local host.
2. Preferences --> Proxy Settings ---> Exclude
3. can specify mutliple servers by comma seperated values

**Research / Observation on my system:**

1. Strangely the same test suite runs without an issue on other system
   within same office. Must be something to do with the way systems are
   configured.
2. Playing with Proxy settings in Internet Options has no
       effect.
3. For my request, Proxy authentication was required. But when
   i enable Proxy settings i get Http Client protocol exception with
   duplicate content length error.
4. We can find this from the http log
   once the request is sent...But we don't have an option to configure
   it.
5. An interesting observation was that one of the content length
   header was in Incoming Request and the other one was in Outgoing
   Request...This shouldn't throw off the request though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to cause this error is to call the web service with the wrong password (I was told wrong honest) too many times and get your account locked.

As soon as the password was reset and the account unlocked the "org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException caused by org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present" exception went away and the web service call worked as expected.